# VBA - Combobox disabled after hidding/bringing-back via Commandbutton

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, hide

I am trying to shrink parts of my excel table which include a couple of Comboboxes. These Comboboxes are filled.

If I hide them and bring them back, they are not selectable anymore. They appear, but I can´t click on them or drop down. They are disabled in some way. I tried all kinds of different commands like .enable, .activate and so on, but nothing seemed to work.

This is my current piece of code:

```
Dim Bereich
Dim shpShape As Shape
Dim j As Integer

Set Bereich = Worksheets("Sanierungskosten").Rows("69:171")
Bereich.Hidden = True = Not (Bereich.Hidden)

For Each shpShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shpShape.TopLeftCell.Row >= 69 And shpShape.TopLeftCell.Row <= 171 Then
        If Rows("69:171").Hidden Then
            shpShape.Visible = False
        Else
            shpShape.Visible = True
       End If
    End If

Next shpShape
```

This is part of my uni-work, I am going crazy on this bug!

Comment: Why do you manually hide your Shapes? 
_Right click -> Format control -> Properties Tab -> Move and size with cells_ This automatically hides your shapes when the rows are hidden.

Comment: Because the part of my table includes a lot of shapes that are not Active-X Shapes. It´s not possible to select the "move and size with cells" attribute on the Shades I am using (without Active-X).

Comment: Can you try on another computer? Does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: That didn´t do the trick, either. The issue is the same.

Comment: Have you considered using Data Validation instead of ComboBoxes? In my experience having lots of controls on spreadsheets is a maintenance hassle.